# What's the best way to declare a string?

Tags: javascript

I have a variety of strings in javascript, here's one:

```
var myString = "hello"
```

What's the best way to declare a string in javascript?

Comment: With a semicolon at the end it would be perfect

Comment: Javascript doesn't have "types" persay so you can't really force a variable to be a String.

Comment: "best" is a fuzzy word. It means different things to different people in different situations.  You already have a way to define a string.  Why not use it?!  Why is it not good enough?  If you have a clear question, ask it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is probably the quickest and best way to declare a string

```
var myString = "hello";
```

Also this would probably be the quickest and best way to declare an integer

```
var myInt = 15;
```

Answer (score 1):

stick a semi-colon on the end and you're pretty much there.

For better or worse, JavaScript is not strongly typed.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact that you are missing the statement terminator semicolon: you are already declaring a string variable, and there aren't too many possible ways to do it.

Javascript is a dynamically typed language, so the type of a variable is given by its contents. `var` declares a variable, and when the contents of a variable is a string value, the variable is a string variable.